# Why do folded code blocks unfold "automatically" in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, code-folding

While writing code in PhpStorm the folded code blocks unfold automatically. I don't know why and this is making me real crazy. Somebody please help.

Comment: see here https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-autofolding-behavior.html

Comment: @BeingHuman thanks for your response, but this not what I m looking for, my problem is :-  "I created a <select> field with lots of <option> in it and folded that select field. Now when I created a new div below that select field, it automatically unfolds." Hope I explained my issue. And thanx again for your help.

Comment: File a bug report. Stackoverflow is the wrong tree to bark up.

Comment: Not sure if I should upvote a question with suicide note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug -- very annoying bug.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13995 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

**UPDATE:** Current status of the [corresponding ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9308) is "resolved" so it must be working OK in WebStorm v11/PhpStorm v10.